# Why is the angle exactly 1/2 of one of the angles in the isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

I'm sure there's a simple theorem that answers my question, but I'm unsure as to how to formulate the problem (not easy to describe geometry with words): It's a isosceles triangle where you draw a normal line on one of the "hypotenuse" sides, and then you make a right angled triangle out of that. My question is why is the 30 degree angle exactly 1/2 of the 60 degree angles we find in the isosceles triangle?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you have a right triangle, with acute angles $\alpha,\beta$, then $(\alpha + \beta) = 90^\circ$.

When $\alpha = 60^\circ = \frac{2}{3} \times 90^\circ,$

then $\beta = 90^\circ - 60^\circ = 90^\circ\left(1 - \frac{2}{3}\right)$

$= 90^\circ\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \times \alpha.$

Answer (score 0):

You have an equilateral triangle. Bisecting angle $\beta$ and drawing the line through the line segment $AC$ will go through the midpoint. You should be able to convince yourself that angle $\sigma$ has to be 30 degrees from that.